# Hide liberator-bottombar only if not command's output available. (Vimperator)

Tags: javascript, css, vimperator

What I'm trying to do is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053262/vimperator-autohide-statusline), but if I'm executing some command, and that command has an output, I also want to be able to see the command's output, so, here is what I've done:

```
"javascript to hide statusbar
noremap <silent> <F8> :js toggle_bottombar()<CR>
noremap : :js toggle_bottombar('on', true)<CR>:
noremap b :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>b
noremap o :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>o
noremap O :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>O
noremap t :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>t
noremap T :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>T
noremap / :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>/
cnoremap <CR> <CR>:js toggle_bottombar('off')<CR>
cnoremap <Esc> <Esc>:js toggle_bottombar('off')<CR>

:js << EOF 

var executing_command = false;

function toggle_bottombar(p, command) {
  var bb = document.getElementById('liberator-bottombar');
  if (!bb)
    return;
if (p == 'on'){
    executing_command = (command === true) ? true : false; 
    bb.style.height = ''; 
    bb.style.overflow = ''; 
    return;
}   
if (p == 'off'){
    if (!executing_command){
        bb.style.height = '0px';
        bb.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    } else {
        toggle_bottombar('on');             
    }  
    return;
}   

bb.style.height = (bb.style.height == '') ? '0px' : ''; 
bb.style.overflow = (bb.style.height == '') ? '' : 'hidden';
}
toggle_bottombar();
EOF
```

And that *half-works* because when I type a command it keeps showing the status bar after I press enter but the output is missing, do you have any ideas for reaching this?

I tried with `:help style` but that doesn't help too much... not enough docs in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally reached what I was trying to. With this little changes you can see commands' outputs and keep the auto-hide functionality.

```
noremap <silent> <F8> :js toggle_bottombar()<CR>
noremap : :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>:
noremap b :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>b
noremap o :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>o
noremap O :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>O
noremap t :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>t
noremap T :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>T
noremap / :js toggle_bottombar('on')<CR>/
noremap <Esc> <Esc>:js toggle_bottombar('off')<CR>
cnoremap <CR> <CR>:js toggle_bottombar('off')<CR>
cnoremap ` <CR> g<

:js << EOF
function toggle_bottombar(p) {
     var bb = document.getElementById('liberator-bottombar');
     if (!bb)
         return;
    if (p == 'on'){
        bb.style.height = '';
        bb.style.overflow = '';
        return;
    }   
    if (p == 'off'){
        bb.style.height = '0px';
        bb.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        return;
      }

     bb.style.height = (bb.style.height == '') ? '0px' : '';
     bb.style.overflow = (bb.style.height == '') ? '' : 'hidden';
}       
toggle_bottombar();
EOF
```

This vimperator's doc guided me to the answer: liberator://help/message#more-prompt, and if you play with liberator components within vimperator's console, it is pretty much self explanatory.

The only disadvantage of doing this, is that whenever you want to see a command's output you need to use "`" (tilda), but i couldn't figure out a better way.

**Note:** It is necessary to press `<Esc>` two times for hiding entirely *bottombar* from command's output, first time command-line is hided and *bottombar* is showed, second time it does what it was desired. I guess it isn't the cleanest way to do it, but that doesn't belong to the original issue.